# Cannot read csv file in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a [csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jP2wWrtSCwLQ50kJSZ5qciVYQ5S6j0by/view?usp=sharing) in Pandas. The file seems in a strange format I downloaded from LinkedIN campaign manager. Can you help me read this file normally? Here is the code:

```
path = r'C:\Users\FilePath' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
dfAllDataLI = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files), ignore_index=True)
```

Here is the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call 

last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11340/2382686370.py in <module>
      3 path = r'C:\Users\n' # use your path
      4 all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
----> 5 dfAllDataLI = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files), ignore_index=True)
      6 dfAllDataLI = dfAllDataLI.fillna('')
      7 

c:\Userspackages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

c:\Usersshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    292     ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['a']
    293     """
--> 294     op = _Concatenator(
    295         objs,
    296         axis=axis,

c:\Useronda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    346             objs = [objs[k] for k in keys]
...
c:\Useda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

c:\Users\ackages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

#### File

```
Campaign Performance Report (in UTC)                                                                
Report Start: April 1, 2022, 12:00 AM                                                               
Report End: April 19, 2022, 11:59 PM                                                                
Date Generated: September 7, 2022, 1:12 PM                                                              
                                                                
Start Date (in UTC) Account Name    Campaign Group Name Campaign Group ID   Campaign Name   Campaign ID Campaign Type   Campaign Start Date Campaign Group Start Date   Campaign End Date   Total Budget    Clicks  Impressions Average CPM Average CPC Avg. Last Day Reach Video Completions
4/19/2022   Wiener Stadtwerke GmbH_iprospect    WST_Content_Promotion_2022  622214964   14.04. | Spendeaktion UKR | reach   194421704   Sponsored Update    4/19/2022   3/8/2022    4/30/2022   600 23  3109    17.22   2.33    3096    58
```

Comment: There are 5 header lines, blank included, so try passing `skiprows=5` to `read_csv`.

Comment: @AKX is correct. also if you have only one file why iterating through many?

Comment: Yes, I have one file, but the code is to acoomodate multiple files in the future. Yea I tried skiprows=5 and still get same error.

Comment: You aren't even telling us what error you get, you know. :)

Comment: sorry, i update the questions with the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file has 5 non-CSV rows before the column header.

Happily, `read_csv` allows you to skip those lines. You'll also need to specify the text encoding (it's UTF-16LE, not UTF-8) and separator for that file (it's tab-separated):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv file.csv', skiprows=5, encoding='utf-16le', sep='\t')
print(df.columns)
```

outputs

```
Index(['Start Date (in UTC)', 'Account Name', 'Campaign Group Name',
       'Campaign Group ID', 'Campaign Name', 'Campaign ID', 'Campaign Type',
       'Campaign Start Date', 'Campaign Group Start Date', 'Campaign End Date',
       'Total Budget', 'Clicks', 'Impressions', 'Average CPM', 'Average CPC',
       'Avg. Last Day Reach', 'Video Completions'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: How did you find encoding of said file?

Comment: @Daweo `$ file "csv file.csv"`: `csv file.csv: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text`